# How to turn Ecto select queries into structs in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've got two models, Song and Vote, where songs has many votes. I want to select all songs and count the number of votes for each.

The index action in the SongController, generated using the mix gen task, has been modified to this:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  query = from s in Song, select: %{id: s.id, name: s.name, artist: s.artist} 
  songs = Repo.all(query)
  render(conn, "index.html", songs: songs)
end
```

In this case `songs` contains a list of lists. But in the orginal, generated function, `songs = Repo.all(Song)` it is a list of *Song structs*.

This means that the song_path functions in the template break with the following error message: `maps cannot be converted to_param. A struct was expected, got: %{artist: "Stephen", id: 3, name: "Crossfire"}`

Of course, what I *really* want to do is to somehow add a `num_votes` field to the select statement, and then somehow make a corresponding field to the Song struct?

Comment: I see that Hex.pm solves a similar problem (number of downloads of a package) by having completely separate lists. ([Controller](https://github.com/hexpm/hex_web/blob/master/web/controllers/package_controller.ex#L24), [View](https://github.com/hexpm/hex_web/blob/master/web/templates/package/index.html.eex#L67))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First we should add a [virtual field](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3) to the song schema so that it can be used to store the `num_votes` result:

```
defmodule Song do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "songs" do
    field :num_votes, :integer, virtual: true
    ...
  end
end
```

Using a combination of [Ecto.Query.select/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#select/3), [Ecto.Query.join/5](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5) and [Ecto.Query.API.count/1](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#count/1) we can add the counts to the map you are using to select from the query:

```
  query = from s in Song,
    left_join: v in assoc(:votes),
    select: %{id: s.id, name: s.name, artist: s.artist, num_votes: count(v.id)}
```

We can then use [Kernel.struct](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Kernel.html#struct/2) to convert each item to a struct:

```
  songs =
    query
    |> Repo.all()
    |> Enum.map(fn(song) -> struct(Song, song) end)
```

This returns a list of song structs that can be used in the view.

Comment: is there a way to not enumerate all fields in select part of the query but say to ecto "hey, select all the fields from the schema plus this num_votes: count() column"?

Comment: for one virtual field I've found solution: `select: %{s | num_votes: count(v.id)}`, but I've stuck on adding more then one.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting thing to note is that structs are actually just dicts with a `__struct__` key set to the module name they are a part of. Because of this you can turn a normal Struct into a Dict by simply removing the `__struct__` key.

```
iex(1)> defmodule M do
...(1)> defstruct [:a, :b]
...(1)> end

iex(2)> Map.delete(%M{}, :__struct__)
%{a: nil, b: nil}
```

(reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/2xQqFOZSvk0)

However you want to go the other direction so it's easy to just add it in the same manner using `Map.add`. Please note to get this to work *all the keys must be there,* even if you're just setting them to `nil`.

So for the other part of you're question. There's probably some fancy SQL way to get the counts. I would recommend you do that. I for one would probably just hack it together in elixir using a join and then `Enum.map`ing over it and replacing the counts with an integer rather than a list. Here's an article about how to do the joins: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/.

I leave it to you as to how to do that.